# Хранение байтов в postgresql

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql

у меня есть текст, который приходит от пользователя (в нем могут иметься эмодзи). И нужно как то сохранить в базе данных тот текст, который пришел от пользователя. Думал над тем, чтобы перевести сообщение в кодировку utf-8, и хранить в базе данных, но выдает ошибку. Вот код:

```
text_code = (message.text).encode('utf-8')
            
insert_call(f"INSERT INTO catalog (product_name, id) VALUES ({text_code}, {catalog_id});")
update_call("UPDATE users SET admin_panel=%s WHERE chat_id=%s;", (catalog_id, message.chat.id))
```

Тип колонки `id` BYTEA

Ошибка:

```
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jaNeight\Desktop\rutor-shop\automate-shop\telegram.py", line 188, in polling
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
  File "C:\Users\jaNeight\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 658, in polling
    self.__threaded_polling(non_stop, interval, timeout, long_polling_timeout, allowed_updates)
  File "C:\Users\jaNeight\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 720, in __threaded_polling
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\jaNeight\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 680, in __threaded_polling
    self.worker_pool.raise_exceptions()
  File "C:\Users\jaNeight\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 135, in raise_exceptions
    raise self.exception_info
  File "C:\Users\jaNeight\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\util.py", line 87, in run
    task(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\jaNeight\Desktop\rutor-shop\automate-shop\telegram.py", line 159, in handle_message
    insert_call(f"INSERT INTO catalog (product_name, id) VALUES ({text_code}, {catalog_id});")
  File "c:\Users\jaNeight\Desktop\rutor-shop\automate-shop\dbase.py", line 28, in insert_call
    cursor.execute(call)
  File "C:\Users\jaNeight\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extras.py", line 146, in execute
    return super().execute(query, vars)
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "lDoZnKGDPRyzLSpyMZbhZesCfkxvvEiEDqZkvJdgkeUAxNeSMhoe"
LINE 1: ...roduct_name, id) VALUES (b'\xf0\x9f\x92\x8e', 2966lDoZnKGDPR...
```

Comment: И какая ошибка?

Comment: @AlexanderChernin добавил ошибку

Comment: Кавычки вроде бы на до добавить, все-таки это строки ('{text_code}', {catalog_id})

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Добавил, но выдает теперь такое: psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO catalog (product_name, id) VALUES ('b'\xf0\x9f\x...

Comment: Может так  (\'{text_code}\')

Comment: @AlexanderChernin То же самое psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO catalog (product_name, id) VALUES ('b'\xf0\x9f\x...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135630/discussion-between-iorisempai-and-alexander-chernin).

Comment: Вместо ручного составления sql-запроса используйте биндинги (binding), тогда проблема передачи ляжет на драйвер, что-то типа: `insert_call("INSERT INTO catalog (product_name, id) VALUES (%s, %s);", [text_code, catalog_id])`, правда я не знаю что за `insert_call`, возможно ваша функция, тогда или в ней нужно поддержать передачу аргументов или самостоятельно вызывать типа вместо `insert_call` будет `con.execute` https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#basic-module-usage и для передачи байтов https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#binary-adaptation

Answer (score 0):

Формат колонок `VARCHAR`, и вместо `{text_code}, {catalog_id}` -> `'{text_code}', '{catalog_id}'`